# Integration of a function not defined at a point

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I have a function $f(x)=(x^2-4)/(x-2)  $.

What will be its integration if i integrate it on interval $[1,3] $ where its not defined on $x=2$?

Does this undefined point effect the result of the integration ? Please explain it briefly and thank you in advance.

Comment: do you mean that you want to know the area covered by this function from $x=1$ to $x=3$ ?

Comment: @Yassir Yeah the area ? and what if there exists more than one undefined points

Comment: well basically you should split the integral into two parts, the first one goes from $1$ to $2^+$, and the second goes from $2^-$ to 3, because the function is not defined in $x=2$

Comment: What yassir commented, with the exception of the intervals going from $1$ to $2^-$ and from $2^+$ to $3$, assuming that my syntax of one sided limits is not wrong.  The math expressions are $$\lim_{b \to 2^-} \int_1^b f(x) dx + \lim_{a\to 2^+} \int_a^3 f(x) dx.$$  Each limit must separately exist, or it's **no dice**.

Comment: Per your comment question of what if there exists more than one undefined point, each undefined point must be given the same treatment.  Therefore, if there are 2 undefined points in the region, you have 3 integrals, 3 undefined points $\to$ 4 integrals, and so forth.

Comment: Or note that $\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}=x+2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the area from $x=1$ to $x=3$ you should take this integral $$\int_1^3f(x)\,dx=\int_1^3 \frac{x^2-4}{x-2}\,dx$$
but since the function $f(x)$ is not defined in the point $x=2$, you should split the integral into two parts $$\int_1^2 \frac{x^2-4}{x-2}\,dx+\int_2^3 \frac{x^2-4}{x-2}\,dx$$

and because the limit from the right side is equal to the limit from the left side, we don't have to put $2^+$ or $2^-$:
$$\int_1^2 x+2\,dx+\int_2^3{x+2}\,dx=\frac{7}{2}+\frac{9}{2}=8$$

read this to understand more about [Improper integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral)